# one to many join

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have two table the first one is with 3 columns As

CR_GENERAL:

```
  CRNO, | mainCR | CR status  
 -------|--------|------------ 
    555 | Null   | not act 
   5647 | 555    | act     
   7845 | 555    | not act 
    434 | Null   | act    
    566 | 434    | act     
   675  | null   | not act 
    778 | null    | act    
   768  | null   | Can     
  8668  | 555    | can
```

Second table (IDENTIFICATIONS):

```
     Cr | partner 
 --------|--------- 
  555    | 23453
  434    | 23555
  768    | 26653
  8668   | 23453
  5647   | 23453
```

First thing I want to do is :

to make all the mainCR Active when ever the Sub is Active.
How ?

In this case in the first table when ever the MainCR is null then the CRNO is the MAINCR and the other thing when ever the CRNO is active the mainCR need to be active as well even if it is not active in this case

555 should be active because 5647 is active and 768 should be active as well

Second step :

I need to create table which includes mainCR with all other CR with it and Including all the status for these CR and Join it with the IDENTIFICATIONS table to add the ID because at the end I need to get the ID status with all CR including with this ID

The result at the end I want it to be something similar to this:

```
  partner| main CR | Sub CR   | Sub CR2 | Sub CR3 | Status
 --------|---------|------------------------------
  23453  | 555     |   5647   |  7845   | 8668    |  Act-not Act -can -Act
  23555  | 434     |    566   | Null    | Null    |  Act - Act
  26653  | 768     |   Null   | Null    | Null    |  Can
```

I tried a lot of queries but with no luck I need ur help in this one

I am fine to have status in different columns as long as these are in the same row

Comment: *"I tried a lot of queries but with no luck I need ur help in this one "* Then why haven't you included them in your question? Please do share them so we can help you fix them; it's very difficult to help debug code when you don't have a copy of it. You've also tagged 2 different RDBMS (SQL Server and MySQL), which are completely different products. Please update your question and tag **only** the RDBMS you are *actually* using. Thank you.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. This looks like a simply join and string aggregation using `group by` and e.g. `string_agg()` in Postgres

Comment: Please find out how to use sentences in English. PS This is unintelligible.

Comment: Posted on behalf of @Jesper: You haven't specified what the CRstatus 'can' is meant to mean in this context.

Also, the status report you give as an example is contradicting:

Partner 23555 is only using CR 434 - but you still list SubCR 566 as active on that line, suggesting you want the status of SubCR's regardless of partner usage.

Partner 26653 is only using CR 768 - but you DON'T list SubCR 778 even though its active, suggesting you ONLY want the status of CR's used by the partner.

Could you clarify what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: select distinct (m.MAIN_CR),m.crstatus,I.PARTNER

from (select 
   case
      when  maincr ='NULL' then crno  
       else  maincr 
   end  MAIN_CR,crstatus,CRNO
from CR_GENERAL ) M inner Join
IDENTIFICATIONS I
  ON M.CRNO = I.ID_NUMBER     " I tried this one but I am sure it is not correct because I do not know how to deal with status "

Comment: Phlilipxy " 23555 is the ID for the mainCR 434 and CRNO 566 " because 434 is the main for the 566 so they will have the same ID with different status for each CR " I am trying to get the different status for each ID